# How can I build connections among four OSs, especially between two Ubuntus?

Tags: connection, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-workstation, intranet

**More background information:**

1. Two Ubuntu 14.x systems both hosted in Windows using VMware Workstation 10: **Ubuntu server** in **Windows 7** and ***Ubuntu guest*** in ***Windows 8.1***.
2. Public IP is limited, so using a single one is the best.

**I want to:**

1. build connections between the two Ubuntus via SSH if possible.(one-way already: from guest Ubuntu to the server)
2. creat a LAN for these four systems and the LAN accesses the Internet using that one public IP which should be the best to be used by the Ubuntu server.

I've partially solved this problem using the recommended method by @maudam and under the help of [this article](http://websistent.com/vmware-bridged-networking/), but to get Ubuntu server in the same network(the Internet) I should set it an other public IP.

It's said that using the bridged networking, the virtual machine must has its own IP address on the external network. But it's hard for me and unnecessary to get an other separate IP. [This documentation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006955) says that it's possible to only employ **NAT networking** to tackle this problem. Can I create a **virtual virtualization lab**(LAN), with this intranet accesses the Internet through the only public IP starting with 219 in the Ubuntu server?

In short, it's it possible to use one public IP to get them all connected to each other? I mean I need **NAT traversal techniques**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For point 1: If you want to access the two VMware hosted Ubuntus via SSH, the simpler way is to change the config from `NAT` to `bridged`. In this way you can assign a LAN IP address to the guests amd hosts can be reached on the LAN.

For point 2: All three guests should already be able to use git on the server providing that network config for the guest is bridged and not NAT.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason not too, bridging and using internally routable IP's (10.*.*.*, 192.168.*.*, etc) configured statically is a fast, straightforward approach.

Comment: @maudam [It's said](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-3B504F2F-7A0B-415F-AE01-62363A95D052.html) that using the bridged networking, the virtual machine must have its own IP address on the external network. But it's hard for me and unnecessary to get an other separate IP.

Comment: @maudam [This documentation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006955) says that it's possible to only harness NAT networking to tackle this problem. Can I create a virtual virtualization lab(LAN) with this intranet accesses the Internet through the only public IP starting with 219?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You modified your questions adding some additional info. It's better if you write down a simple network schema of your actual network (real and virtual with router details) and what you need to accomplish. As far as i can understand, your public ip address could be used only on the router which will perform NAT translations (and port publishing) to the private LAN addresses. This should be the right config for your needs.